# how to validate the hour that is being booked?

Tags: php, laravel

| id | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-10-10 11:00:00 | 2022-10-10 15:00:00 |

I have a data row in the booking table as above, I want when there is input **start_date : 2022-10-10 12:00:00 or 2022-10-10 13:00:00 or 2022-10-10 14:00:00**, because at that time it was still in the booking range like the example table above,

How do I validate it so that the user cannot add the time that is included in the booking range?

Comment: You don't want the user to choose the time ?

Comment: In what format do you receive the user input on the backend? Do you receive it as time / date-time?

Comment: Try to be more clear about what you want to achieve

Comment: I use select option to choose the time

Comment: when the user selects an hour that is already in the booking range and he submits, after that it is processed in the backend / controller,

Comment: datetime format

Comment: @stackoverflow [Check overlaping timeslots for laravel query](https://www.anycodings.com/1questions/5178517/check-overlaping-timeslots-for-laravel-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should point you in the right direction.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class BookingController extends Controller
{
    function book(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            "booking_start_date" => [
                "required",
                "date_format:Y-m-d H:i:s",

                function ($attribute, $value, $fail) use ($request) {

                    $booking = \App\Models\Booking::where([
                        ["start_date", "<=", $request->booking_start_date],
                        ["end_date", ">=", $request->booking_start_date],
                    ])->orWhere([
                        ["start_date", "<=", $request->booking_end_date],
                        ["end_date", ">=", $request->booking_end_date],
                    ])->first();

                    if ($booking) {
                        $fail(
                            sprintf("An appointment between '%s' and '%s' has already been booked. Please, try booking again outside this range.",
                                \Carbon\Carbon::create($booking->start_date)->format("d M Y H:i"),
                                \Carbon\Carbon::create($booking->end_date)->format("d M Y H:i")
                            )
                        );
                    }

                },
            ],

            "booking_end_date" => [
                "required",
                "date_format:Y-m-d H:i:s",
                "after:booking_start_date",
            ],

        ]);
        
        // Create/insert new data below this line of code.
        $newBooking = \App\Models\Booking::create([
            "start_date" => $request->booking_start_date,
            "end_date" => $request->booking_end_date,
        ]);

        return response()->json($newBooking);

    }
}
```

[Using Closures](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#using-closures)

> If you only need the functionality of a custom rule once throughout
> your application, you may use a closure instead of a rule object. The
> closure receives the attribute's name, the attribute's value, and a
> `$fail` callback that should be called if validation fails:

Comment: if I add a booking schedule that is outside the range, it still goes to "$fail(......)

Comment: @stackoverflow Oops!, Sorry. Please, check my edited answer again.

Comment: if outside the time range in which part of the code can I create new data?

Comment: if ($booking) {
                        $fail(
                            sprintf(")
                            )
                        );
                    }else{
                        // create data
                    }
I tried the else part but failed to create data

Comment: @stackoverflow Check my edited answer. Add new data below the comment `// Create/insert new data below this line of code.`

Comment: @stackoverflow If in case you're using the `\App\Models\Booking::create(...)` method, ensure that the column names ('start_date' & 'end_date') are defined in the model's `protected $fillable = [...];` array property.

Comment: if I book from 08:00 to 11:00, and someone else book from 07:00 to 12:00, it shouldn't be possible because the time 08:00 and 11:00 are already booked, but logic now can do this the,